# How to use Page Speed Insight API in localhost with PHP?

Tags: php, pagespeed-insights

Hi I am trying to get the page speed insights using google speed insights API in PHP

```
$api = 'API KEY';
$url = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/';
$url_sh = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=".$url."&key=".$api;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_sh);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

But getting NULL value as a result

I also tried `json_decode` but getting the same output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version 1 api was deprecated a loooong time ago, the latest version is version 5, so you just need to change your url to

`https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=".$url."&key=".$api;`

You can [read the getting started documents here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/get-started)

Comment: I removed the part about the `NULL` return as actually it returns a 404 not found which I didn't realise, I thought it was still a 200 from the server and the "Not Found" was just some status text from the API.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the 'Google Get Started' documentation advising the use of the domain:

`https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed`

for page speed insights, I find that the url:

`https://pagespeedonline.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed`

is more reliable for runPageSpeed.

I use the cURL options shown below to run Page Speed Insights:

```
$api = 'API KEY';
$url = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/';
$url_sh = "http://pagespeedonline.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=".$url."&key=".$api;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURL_TIMEOUT, 200);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_sh);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER option set to 0 is essential for the code to run.